# IIS FTP Folder Access Issues (550)

Tags: windows, ftp, iis

I'm trying to connect to our FTP on an IIS server and I'm having issues viewing files/folders.  My manager is able to connect with no issues and it's been a long time since he set it up. We added a Windows account for me and I'm able to connect, but unable to access folders.  We set the permissions on the server so I have full control, but it still doesn't seem to want to allow me to access it.  Any idea what we might be missing?  We've tried restarting the FTP service, but that didn't seem to work either.

FileZilla logs:

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    CWD /folder_name
Response:   550 Cannot create a file when that file already exists. 
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

CMD:

```
ftp> cd folder_name
550 Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

Comment: "We set the permissions on the server so I have full control"  Can you expand on what you did exactly?  Did you ensure that account has permission to access the folders/files themselves (at the Windows file system level)? Can you create your own new folders successfully? Are you on the LAN with the FTP server? Is the server setup to be Passive or Active?

Comment: Yes, we set the permissions on the folders themselves.  I have full access when I RDP into the server.

I am able to create folders in the root FTP directory.  I just can't delve any deeper with the folder that my manager has been working in.  The permissions of that folder are inherited from the root dir.

We're connecting remotely over WAN.

We're using Active.  Passive won't connect for either of us.

Comment: So if you do create a folder in the root (via FTP), can you CWD into it? If so, then there's something whacky about that folder you're trying to access. Are the folder(s) you're having trouble with virtual directories or regular folder directly in the FTP site's file structure?

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to access the folder I created with no issues. It's a regular folder on the drive of the server.  Perhaps I'll try tinkering with just that problem folder's permissions a bit more...

Comment: Definitely sounds like a folder permissions issue to me, but odd you can get into it when logged in via RDP (same user account I'm assuming, right?).  Perhaps the easiest "fix" is for you to make a new folder, then get your boss to copy the work to it and delete his original folder, and then just work from the folder you can both access. :)

Comment: Haha yeah, same user account and everything.  I redid the permissions for myself and.... Still no luck. We may consider recreating the folder though.

Comment: One last thought, ensure you're setting the permissions for the folder to apply to that folder and all files and folders inside it (don't assume they are inheriting).  My thinking is that if you don't have permission (or have a Deny permission) in place to a file in that folder it may throw that error when trying to show the contents.

Comment: Tried that, and same error :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out last week.  In the C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config file, there was an extra set of permissions for the problem sub-directory that was causing the issues.  Once I removed that, it worked as expected...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, receiving the following message when logged in to an IIS 8.5 FTP server:

ftp> cd folder_name
550 Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

I believe the problem started after changing the physical path of the FTP site when FTP authorization settings had already been applied. The fix was to delete the FTP site from within IIS, point it to the correct physical path, then re-apply authorization settings via the "FTP Authorization Rules" icon.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one cause for this issue. It doesn't help that FTP doesn't accurately report the nature of the error. First, check the obvious. Make sure your FTP user account has the correct permissions to the ftp site. Second, make sure the ftp directory or any of the files you will be replacing isn't marked "read-only." Finally, check the least obvious cause, is your website still running in IIS? If so, stop the site and try it again. Quite often, the application worker process has one or more of your files open.